# Array dentro de Array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

Estou criando um sisteminha onde pode ser adicionar medicamentos por protocolos. 
Ex:
   NOME DO PROTOCOLO

```
    [ARRAY]
    NOME DO REMÉDIO
    [ARRAY 2]
    NOME DO ITEM        QUANTIDADE         TEMPO DE INFUSÃO [ARRAY] 
    NOME DO ITEM 2      QUANTIDADE 2       TEMPO DE INFUSÃO 2 [ARRAY]
    [ARRAY]
    NOME DE UM NOVO REMÉDIO
    NOME DO ITEM        QUANTIDADE         TEMPO DE INFUSÃO   [ARRAY]
    NOME DO ITEM 2      QUANTIDADE 2       TEMPO DE INFUSÃO 2 [ARRAY]
    NOME DO ITEM 3      QUANTIDADE 3       TEMPO DE INFUSÃO 3 [ARRAY]
```

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
$codigo = rand(5, 50000);
  // $codigo = uniqueAlfa(6);
  $itemA = $_POST['item'];
  $nomePres = $_POST['nome-item'];
   foreach ($itemA as $itemB):
     foreach (array($_POST['nome']) as $val1):
       foreach (array($_POST['tmp']) as $tmp):
    foreach (array($_POST['qtd']) as $val2):
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($val1); $i++):
        if($cadastra = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ifro_prescricao_medicamentos 
                  (id_prescricao, nome, item_padrao, item, quantidade, tempo_infusao) 
                  VALUES 
                 ('$codigo','$nomePres', '$itemB', '".$val1[$i]."', '".$val2[$i]."', '".$tmp[$i]."')")) {

          }  
        endfor;
      endforeach;
    endforeach;
  endforeach;
 endforeach;
```

Mas ele esta sempre cadastrando todos os itens iguais, não esta separando os nome do remédios
veja a imagem: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Seguem as imagens em como é o meu form de cadastro das informações:

Esta imagem esta com apenas 1 medicamento
[image: Esta imagem esta com apenas 1 medicamento]
Esta imagem já com 2 medicamentos
[image: Esta imagem já com 2 medicamentos]

Answer (score 1):

A variável $código é a mesma porque está fora do foreach, ela deveria ser colocada dentro para que seja gerado um novo número aleatório a cada iteração.

O mesmo vale para a variável $nomePres, ela tem que ir para dentro do foreach.

Agora quanto ao restante, me parece que a lógica não está boa. Estou vendo que você recebe 5 valores via método POST: item, nome-item, nome, tmp e qtd. Esses 5 POSTS recebem arrays do mesmo tamanho? Deveriam receber para que uma tabela fosse corretamente preenchida. Outra coisa, os valores recebidos via POST saíram de inputs de formulário HTML? Se sim, o atributo name deve conter o nome seguido de colchetes. Por exemplo o valor recebido tmp deve estar em um input name="tmp[]".

Reescrevendo o código:

```
$itemA = $_POST['item'];

  $nomePres = $_POST['nome-item'];

  $nome = $_POST['nome'];

  $tmp = $_POST['tmp'];

  $qtd = $_POST['qtd'];

  $contador = 0;

  foreach ($itemA as $itemB) {

    $codigo = rand(5, 50000);

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ifro_prescricao_medicamentos
            SET id_prescricao = '$codigo',
            nome = '$nome[$contador]',
            item_padrao = '$itemB',
            item = '$nome[$contador]',
            quantidade = '$qtd[$contador]',
            tempo_infusao = '$tmp[$contador]'");

    $contador++;

  }
```

Comment: Mas ele não faz o array dentro de cada um deles, vou mandar a foto do meu form.

Comment: Segue o link da imagem 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8tOx.png

Comment: A variável `$codigo` é realmente necessária? não se pode apenas alterar a coluna `id_prescricao ` para `AUTO INCREMENT` ?

Comment: Sim ela é necessária, pois preciso recuperar ela depois, tipo o a prescrição 1029 tem o item 1, 2, 3 com medicamentos 4, 6 , 7, entendeu?

Answer (score 0):

Desculpa a demora, talvez já tenha conseguido resolver. De qualquer forma vamos lá.

Só me confirme o seguinte quanto aos POSTS recebidos:

- 'item' vem do input 'protocolo';
- 'nome-item' vem do input 'remedio 1, remedio 2, etc';
- 'nome' vem do input 'nome do remédio';
- 'qtd' vem do input 'quantidade';
- 'tmp' vem do input 'tempo infusão'.

Outra coisa, deve ser gerado um código para cada protocolo ou para cada remédio?

Realmente deve haver um foreach dentro de outro, acho que o código fica da seguinte forma:

```
$itemA = $_POST['item'];

$nomePres = $_POST['nome-item'];

$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$tmp = $_POST['tmp'];

$qtd = $_POST['qtd'];

$contador = 0;

foreach ($itemA as $itemB) {

    $codigo = rand(5, 50000);

    foreach ($nomePres as $nomeRemedio) {

        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ifro_prescricao_medicamentos
            SET id_prescricao = '$codigo',
            nome = '$nome[$contador]',
            item_padrao = '$itemB',
            item = '$nome[$contador]',
            quantidade = '$qtd[$contador]',
            tempo_infusao = '$tmp[$contador]'");

        $contador++;

    }

}
```

O primeiro foreach dá conta do protocolo, o segundo foreach da conta do remédio, e o contador dentro desse segundo foreach dá conta de ler ao mesmo tempo os arrays item, quantidade e tempo de infusão.

Apesar que se o protocolo sempre for um só de cada vez, nem precisava desse primeiro foreach.

Só uma observação, sempre procure usar nomes de variáveis o mais próximo possível do que elas representem, porque senão fica muito fácil se perder. Por exemplo, nos POSTS você recebe item, nome-item e nome, e chama elas de $itemA, $itemB, $nome, $nomePres é muito fácil confundir e difícil saber a que correspondem.

Comment: Leandro, desculpe minha ignorância, mas esta dando o seguinte erro Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in F:\wamp\www\froc\sistema\acao\insere-prescricao-medicamento.php on line 48

Comment: Vamos lá,não havia entendido sua pergunta:

'nome-protocolo' - seria o nome do PROTOCOLO

'medicamento[]' - nome do remédio
'nome-item[]' - seria o nome do item
'qtd' - quantidade do item
'tmp' - tempo de infusão

Lembrando que todos ele pode ter vários remédios (medicamentos) com outros itens dentro deles
Medicamento 1
                      ITEM A         QUANTIDADE A      TEMPO INFUSÃO A
                      ITEM A-1      QUANTIDADE A-1      TEMPO INFUSÃO A-1

MEDICAMENTO 2
                      ITEM 2          QUANTIDADE B      TEMPO INFUSÃO B

Comment: estou fazendo o cadastro mas esta cadastrando o nome dos itens repetidos
Cmo recebo: 
string 'medicamento' (length=11)


string 'ITEM 1' (length=6)
string 'item 2' (length=6)
string 'item 3' (length=6)
string 'item 1-a' (length=8)
string 'medicamento 2' (length=13)
string 'ITEM 1' (length=6)
string 'item 2' (length=6)
string 'item 3' (length=6)
string 'item 1-a' (length=8)

Sendo que o MEDICAMENTO 2 apenas cadastrei um 1 item, e ele trás todos os outros.

Obrigado pela ajuda em tentar resolver essa condição